# When publishing NPM package I get an empty object my setup is (ES6,Babel,Webpack,React,Redux,Sagas)

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Maybe somebody can help me with this.

I try to publish npm package with the following configuration:

## webpack:

```
   production: {
    entry: [
      './src',
      './src/app.scss',
      'draft-js/dist/Draft.css'
    ],
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
      filename: 'stewie-editor.js',
      library: 'stewie-editor',
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      umdNamedDefine: true
    }
  },
```

## package.json section dealing with library publishing

```
  "main": "lib/stewie-editor.js",
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "src"
  ],
```

## My src/index.js file looks like this

```
import EditorComponent from 'EditorComponent';
import EditorFactory from 'EditorFactory';

export {
  EditorFactory,
  EditorComponent
}
```

## .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-add-module-exports"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        ["css-modules-transform", {
            "generateScopedName": "[name]__[local]",
            "extensions": [".css", ".scss"]
        }]
      ]
    },
    "dev": {
      "plugins": [["react-transform", {
        "transforms": [{
          "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
          "imports": ["react"],
          "locals": ["module"]
        }]
      }]]
    }
  }
}
```

## I looked at the following [example](https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter) and there everything is working.

strangely with my setup things don't work

## In a different project when I install stewie-editor npm package and import exported classes from the package like so:

```
import { EditorFactory } from 'stewie-editor';
```

I get undefined. When I try to look at the contents of the whole package importing it like so:

```
import stewie from 'stewie-editor';
```

I get an empty Object.

## Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get an empty object? It would be nice if you could be more specific.

Comment: I've added a section describing how do I import the package

Comment: What is in your `lib/stewie-editor.js` file? This is what you've declared as the main file…

Comment: Yeah this is the output of build process as you can see from webpack configuration

Answer (score 2):

The empty object is as a result of a missing keyword in your `index.js` file: `default`.

You can fix this by rewriting the `index.js` file to:

```
export default {
  EditorFactory,
  EditorComponent
}
```

Comment: Also when trying your suggestion it doesn't work either.

Comment: If you've published the module, I could clone it and take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured out what was the problem. Adding scss and .css in webpack entry point resulted in an empty object. So I removed them from entry point and added as imports inside my EditorComponent.js file. That fixed the issue. Everything got exported.

Comment: I was googling for *hours* and at a point just gave up and tried everything I found. Then I found this comment, and it solved all my issues. If anyone knows exactly why this works, please let me know.